# Webview not loading on Android 10

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have been using this code to load a website, It worked for me on my android 9 mobile, But after I have tested it on an android 10 mobile it's not working what can I do to fix this issue, Help me to fix this, Thanks in advance...

```
 webView = findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       webView.loadUrl(url);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
    {

        if(progress == 100)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: We do not know what you are trying to load.

Comment: check network security config for clear traffic

Comment: @blackapps i am trying to load the Googles website

Comment: Show exact url. Put it in your code.